# PHP - Google Charts

Tags: php, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Charts and i'm having some trouble to create array for API.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts

My source of data has 3 columns, which is quantity, date and user name.
(you can see in attachment).

How to convert his form of array to use with google charts api (line charts)?

I think i need to convert each different value from column "responsavel" to a new column and set these column the value of column "qt_pedido"
In this example, the final array should be something like this:

Date       |  user1  |  user2 
------------------------------- 
03/09/2018 |  58     |   19 
05/09/2019 |  23     |    5  
 
[Result from sql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n7nu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be easier to use google data table methods to transform the rows to columns,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['line']
}).then(function () {
  // create data table
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'responsavel', 'qt_pedido'],
    ['20/10/2018', 'user1', 10],
    ['20/10/2018', 'user2', 20],
    ['20/10/2018', 'user3', 30],
    ['20/11/2018', 'user1', 40],
    ['20/11/2018', 'user2', 50],
    ['20/11/2018', 'user3', 60],
    ['20/12/2018', 'user1', 70],
    ['20/12/2018', 'user2', 80],
    ['20/12/2018', 'user3', 90],
  ]);

  // create data view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  // column arrays
  var aggColumns = [];
  var viewColumns = [0];

  // build view & agg columns for each responsibility
  data.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (responsibility, index) {
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === responsibility) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 2);
        }
        return null;
      },
      label: responsibility,
      type: 'number'
    });

    aggColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: index + 1,
      label: responsibility,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });

  // set view columns
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  // sum view by date
  var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    aggColumns
  );

  // draw chart
  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(aggData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! But just one detail, my date string is PT-BR, so its 'dd/mm/yyyy' and in your example, it shows 'mm/dd/yyyy', how to adjust that? 
Setting the localization to pt-br doesn't works...

Comment: does it help to leave the date as a string? see changed answer above, specifically changed data and --> `var viewColumns = [0];`

Comment: Just what i needed! Thanks! :)

Comment: Another question, how to pass options when drawing chart?
Passing  chart.draw(aggData, options);
Does not work in this example. I need this to set title of chart and dimensions....

Comment: there are several options that do not work with _Material_ charts, check here --> [issues#: 2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- for title, use `chart: {title: 'title'}`